# serial0 owned by root, changes back to after reboot

Tags: serial, permissions

trying to follow some tutorials about accessing serial ports, I kept getting a permission denied error for /dev/serial0, and the common solution seemed to be to add the user to the `dialout` group... except in my case serial0 is owned by `root:root`

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        5 Aug 21 20:16 serial0 -> ttyS0
```

I tried `chown root:dialout /dev/serial0`, and not only did I still get Permission Denied, but upon reboot, the ownership changed back to `root:root`.

almost all documentation and answers I see show this should be `root:dialout`. so what's going on with my install? and how do I get access to the serial port without root?

I'm running a recent install of Pi OS with Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

**EDIT:** turns out I had serial console enabled within `raspi-config`, once I disabled that, and only had serial port enabled, I no longer receieved the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT an error!

`/dev/serial0` is a link; the device to which it links `/dev/ttyAMA0` or `/dev/ttyS0` is a member of dialout.

NOTE unless you enable serial there will be no `/dev/serial0`.

See [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 or later](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)